# Insert using slick does not work

Tags: database, scala, slick

I am new to Scala and have been learning about slick(3.1.1). While writing a particular code to insert data into a table, I have to insert a row if it does not exist else update a particular column in that table. For a single row update I have written the following code, which works fine :

```
 def updateDate(id: Int, country : Country, lastDate: DateTime)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) =
        byPKC.applied((id, country, )).map(_.lastMessageDate).update(lastDate) flatMap {
          case 0 ⇒
            create(User.withLastDate(id, country, lastDate))
          case x ⇒ DBIO.successful(x)
        }
```

Now I am unsure of how to do a bulk operation in scala for this. I tried the following, which even though inefficient, should work but there is no row being inserted into the table.

```
 def updateDates(ids: Set[Int], country: Country, lastDate: DateTime)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) = {
    ids.foreach(e ⇒ updateDate(e, country, lastDate))
    DBIO.successful(1)
  }
```

How do I do a bulk write in scala? Also, why does this bulk operation not work? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Two-part answer to the two-part question.

> How do I do a bulk write in scala?

You can't do bulk updates in SQL; it's simply not supported. You can bulk insert, though. Slick supports bulk inserts with the `++=` operator on `TableQuery`.

> Why does this bulk operation not work?

You're generating the `DBIO` values, but you aren't executing them via `db.run()`. `DBIO` is a mapping of Scala operations to SQL, but you have to execute it before it will be sent to the database.